# Non-admin GeoServer users with advanced privileges

Tags: geoserver, administration

I have user, who has full access to only their workspace. How can I allow him to:

- change their password
- set password protection for reading/writing layers from his workspace
- create own service rules for own workspace/layers

Comment: Voting to leave open - its not a general software development question, its asking how to configure GeoServer permissions.